# Iterative refinement with new data

Tags: matrices

I have a timeseries with enough data points that it's difficult to store it all in memory at once, but would like to solve a linear system of equations using all of it, so I'm looking for a way to solve an initial LU factorization, and then read in pieces at a time from the file to refine the solution to something more accurate.

Do any of you know of a specific technique for doing this sort of thing? I've looked into iterative refinement ([e.g.](http://iris.gmu.edu/~snash/or682-f00/Lecture04/Matlab_files/Heath2_9.m%5d)) but that seems to be more for improving accuracy with the same data rather than new data.

Alternatively, would it be best to just break the $m$ by $n$data points into $n/m$ square matrices and average the resulting coefficients?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into Krylov Subspace Methods?